# Set 2 conditions binded together

Tags: sql

I am not clever at SQL and have a problem to create SP that have 2 lists and I would like to filter in table by this list:
e.g. Inputs to SP
lstNames : Ali ; John 
lstSubjs  : A   ; A

### ScoreTable:

### Name   |    Subject |    Score

### Ali     |    B       |    80

### John    |   A        |    70

My initila script of SP :\

```
Select Score from ScoreTable \
where Name in  SplitStringToTable(lstNames ) and Subject in SplitStringToTable(lstSubjs)
```

SplitStringToTable my function : to split values delimeted by ; to be table

based on my query the result will be : 80 , 70
Result should be                     : 0 , 70
that is wrong as where student=Ali & subject= A the socre is not exist but my query return 80 as it will search inside all available values .

I believ the solution should be bind the 1st condition with 2nd condition as if I search for name=Ahmed I should search for subject at the same record that contain Ahmed (only subject=B) not search for all subjects .

Please advice .

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change this but this will give you some idea. Also take a look at [this.](http://outcoldman.ru/en/blog/show/224)

```
select score
from scoreTable st
Left JOIN dbo.SplitStringToTable(lstNames) name
ON st.name = name.name
LEft jOin dbo.splitStringToTable(lstSubject) sub
oN st.Subject = sub.subject
```